# How to position iOS share dialog by default top-left to top-right of the app?

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am developing an iOS app using Xamarin.Forms. I am using Xamarin.Essentials for sharing CSV file in the app referring the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=ios.

But it shows the share dialog on top left corner in iPad where as I want to have it on top right corner. Can someone please suggest me how to position as I like to?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i think it may be a system setting and you could not change its location

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT In my app the action button is in top right corner, but getting share dialog on top left corner will be weird. In iOS preinstalled apps, share dialog comes on top right only. Then, why Xamarin.Essentials team has designed in such a way to come on top left side?

Comment: maybe you could show a screenshots

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT added the screenshot as requested.

Comment: I see it. I'm sorry that this may not change. Maybe you could go to https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues to give a report.